# Django UniqueConstraint returns error after adding modifying by adding a field to it

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have `UniqueConstraint` on a model and realized I needed to add one more field *(field3)* to prevent double entries but when I did that and I run `python manage.py makemigrations` it works fine but `python manage.py migrate` returns the error below:

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1553, "Cannot drop index 'special_key': needed in a foreign key constraint")`

The initial unique constraint is `models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['field1', 'field2'], name='special_key')`

The new updated unique constraint is `models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['field1', 'field2', 'field3'], name='special_key')`

But I get the error above when I try applying the migration. I use MySQL as my database management system.

Comment: Is the field associated with `bulk_fee_amount_key` used in the previous unique constraint? It seems like the migration file wants to drop this index, which is used as a foreign key.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr it is the same as `special_key`. I have edited the OP.

Comment: If you're using a test database(not containing real data), the simple solution is to drop all entries in the database and try migrating again.

Comment: I have data already in there.